how to draw such gradient background using css?

I take a photo of sunset and I like such gredient effects from sky to highlight sunset, is there any way to simulate such effect using css? I want to erase those buildings then use it as my webpage background.
I have tried background: linear-gradient(to bottom left, rgba(96,98,139,1), rgba(230,202,224,0.8),rgba(254,255,241,0.5));, but it's not ideal

The example you posted with background: linear-gradient(to bottom left, rgba(96,98,139,1), rgba(230,202,224,0.8),rgba(254,255,241,0.5)); looks pretty good to me! I think you need to specify what it is you're not happy with with that, and what aspect you'd like improving, as otherwise I'd just end up writing the exact same thing!

@Snor I don't know how to ajust different ratio of each color, and I hope light area, like circle, take up smaller area

You can layer gradients, with different shapes, colours, opacities, and break points. Here I've done a linear gradient with 3 colours picked from your image. And then Added 3 separate radial gradients stacked on top of each other for the bright yellow centre glow, the pink glow around it, and a lighter halo around that, to attempt to soften the light from the other 2 radial gradients. You can tweak the values to get closer to what you want if it's still not quite right, and also try adding/removing elements so you can see what they are actually doing.


     body {
      height: 100vh;
      background:
        radial-gradient(
          circle at 30% 100%, 
          rgba(255, 255, 200, 1) 0%,
          rgba(255, 255, 200, 0) 20%
        ),
        radial-gradient(
          circle at 30% 100%, 
          rgba(250, 219, 234, 1) 0%,
          rgba(250, 219, 234, 0) 35%
        ),
        radial-gradient(
          circle at 30% 100%, 
          rgba(250, 219, 234, 0.3) 0%,
          rgba(250, 219, 234, 0) 50%
        ),
        linear-gradient(
          200deg, 
          rgba(92, 94, 135, 1) 0%, 
          rgba(154, 143, 175, 1) 50%, 
          rgba(255, 182, 163, 1) 100%
        );
      }




graceful, many thanks

This will work for this background:
background: linear-gradient(to bottom left, #5f618a, #776f94, #ad9db8, #fef7ef);

Make sure that their is some content in web-page.

You can go to cssgradiant.io to search what you want, like center gradiant (good for the sun on the photo), or with linear gradiants, you can choose the angle and so on.
Put this on the background and you will be good

yes, I have checked it and play, it's easy to test all kinds of gradent effects
